# Which SMOTE algorithm should I use for Augmentation of Time Series dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, data-augmentation

I am working on a Time Series Dataset where i want to do forcasting and prediction both. So, if you have any suggestion please share. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

T-Smote
This allows one to both impute fully missing observations to allow uniform time series classification across the entire data and, in special cases, to impute individually missing features. To do so, we slightly generalize the well-known class imbalance algorithm SMOTE to allow component wise nearest neighbor interpolation that preserves correlations when there are no missing features. We visualize the method in the simplified setting of 2-dimensional uncoupled harmonic oscillators. Next, we use tSMOTE to train an Encoder/Decoder long-short term memory (LSTM) model with Logistic Regression for predicting and classifying distinct trajectories of different 2D oscillators.